# Select next and next elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, siblings

Given certain divs I have in a variable **I want to select the next and the one after the next** with jQuery.

At first I thought I could do:

```
$('.element1,.element2').siblings('+.aa, +.aa+.aa')
```

but it seems like I can only do that if I specify the class of each element:

```
$('.element1,.element2').siblings('.element1+.aa, .element1+.aa+.aa, .element2+.aa, .element2+.aa+.aa, .etc')
```

or:

```
$('.element1,.element2').next().add($('.element1,.element2').next().next())
```

My variable has several elements. Is it correct to use the [.siblings() method](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [.next() method](https://api.jquery.com/next/) for this case or is there some other simpler way?

```js
var $next = $('.bb,.cc').next();

$next.add($next.next()).addClass('red');
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

div.red {
  background: red;
}
article {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div class="aa"></div>
  <div class="aa"></div>
  <div class="bb"></div>
  <div class="aa"></div><!–– this ––>
  <div class="aa"></div><!–– this ––>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="aa"></div>
  <div class="aa"></div>
  <div class="cc"></div>
  <div class="aa"></div><!–– this ––>
  <div class="aa"></div><!–– this ––>
</article>
```

Comment: .nextAll() sounds like your friend

Comment: does your demo work like you expect? I'm curious what you want to change in your demo. seems like it does what you want it to do.

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks for taking a look. The demo works, but I have (much) more than two elements in the real case. I wonder if there is a simpler way, as it is right now it looks over complicated just to select the next and next elements.